# Python - Pass class as argument to decorator of method within that class?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm looking to do the following:

```
class A(object):
    def first_method(self):
        print "I'm the first method!"    

    @some_decorator(A.first_method)
    def second_method(self):
        print "I'm the second method!"
```

But I'm running into the problem that `A` is undefined within itself at the time that the decorator is parsed. Is there any way for me to reference `A` in the decorator? Alternatively, if I just pass the decorator the bound method `first_method` is it possible for me to recover that `first_method` belongs to `A`?

Comment: I think this little blog post might be useful: http://scottlobdell.me/2015/04/decorators-arguments-python/

Comment: @FreddieV4, I am aware of how to create a decorator with arguments. The problem, as stated, is that `A` is undefined within itself. Referencing `first_method` from within `A` but outside of a function will return the unbound method `first_method`, not `A.first_method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3, you can just say `@some_decorator(first_method)`, and it will work, as all methods are normal functions in the classes as the containers.

In python 2, there is a complicated system of bound & unbound, instance-, class-, and static methods. Due to this, you cannot access `first_method` while inside of a class definitionm (until the class if fully formed).

A little workaround would be to split that class into two classes:

```
class BaseA(object):
    def first_method(self):
        print "I'm the first method!"    

class A(BaseA):
    @some_decorator(BaseA.first_method)
    def second_method(self):
        print "I'm the second method!"
```

Not the best solution for all cases, but will work.

---

Also, keep in mind, that in both cases (py2 & py3), the decorator will refer to the `first_method` as it was declared here. If any descendant class redefines the method, the new method will NOT be used in the decorator; only the parent one will be used.

Probably, you should not refer to `first_method` at all. Instead, just accept `self`/`cls` first positional argument in the decorator's wrapper, and use `self.first_method`/`cls.first_method` there:

```
import functools

def some_decorator(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        first_method = self.first_method
        first_method()
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A(object):
    def first_method(self):
        print "I'm the first method of A!"    

    @some_decorator
    def second_method(self):
        print "I'm the second method!"


class B(A):
    def first_method(self):
        print "I'm the first method of B!"    


A().second_method()
# I'm the first method of A!
# I'm the second method!

B().second_method()
# I'm the first method of B!
# I'm the second method!
```

If you want to make that method configurable:

```
def some_decorator(method_name):
    def decorator(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            first_method = getattr(self, method_name)
            first_method()
            return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


class A(object):
    def first_method(self):
        print "I'm the first method of A!"    

    @some_decorator('first_method')
    def second_method(self):
        print "I'm the second method!"

class B(A):
    def first_method(self):
        print "I'm the first method of B!"
```

Comment: That last bit there is the answer mate! Having the wrapper accept self will allow the base class to be captured! Great stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your decorator as a classic function (without the @):

```
def some_decorator(arg):
    # ...
    pass


class A(object):
    def first_method(self):
        print("I'm the first method!")

    def second_method(self):
        print("I'm the second method!")


A.second_method = some_decorator(A.first_method)(A.second_method)
```